# Layout right-to-left in HorizontalFieldManager on BlackBerrry

Tags: blackberry

How do I align elements right-to-left in a BlackBerry HorizontalFieldManager?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Is it that fields will be added from right to left or that they start from the rightmost corner of the screen and may have a space between the leftmost and the edge of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

On JDE 6.0, if you want to do this for locale reasons, then setting the HorizontalFieldManager.LOCALE_AWARE_LAYOUT style bit will cause left-to-right or right-to-left, depending on the user's locale.

The [HorizontalFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html) docs for BlackBerry JDE 6.0 mention a style bit Field.LEFT_TO_RIGHT and Field.RIGHT_TO_LEFT, but I don't see those constants in Eclipse, so that may be a documentation bug.

Answer (score -1):

HorizontalFieldManager adds fields from left-to-right by default.  In the following example, the three labels are aligned in one row from left to right.

```
HorizonatalFieldManager hManager=new HorizonatalFieldManager();

LabelField l1=new LabelField("Label1");
LabelField l2=new LabelField("Label2");
LabelField l3=new LabelField("Label3");

hManager.add(l1);
hManager.add(l2);
hManager.add(l3);
```